# Facebook Integration in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5

i am using FBConnect in my project for integration of Facebook.but now i saw in all  apps,when the user tap the Facebook button,it goes directly to the FaceBook App in the device to open for login.i think this is done with URLschema to communicate the App to App in a device.but how can we o this in case of Facebook.

My need is ,i have a sharing option in my app to Facebook,so when the user tap the button it needs to open the Facebook app in the device for login,and after successful login it needs to come back to my app also.how to o this?.is there any sample project or apps to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out ShareKit 2.0. A quick google search will make this easy on you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the FBSessionDelegate.  You provide the delegate which gets callbacks when the FB login completes (successfully or not).  Also the FBConnect code, see git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git, has a sample directory with a Hackbook Xcode project.  That should get you started!

Here is the [Facebook iOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) (which uses FBConnect).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API(Uses OAuth 201 authentication protocol) instead of FBConnect , which is newer and a lot easier.You can implement it inthe following steps:-

1>Get unique id and api key from facebook's develooper portal.

2>Display the login page of the facebook in your app.

3>Allow the user to loginthrough following URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=[API key]&
    redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&
    scope=[extended permissions]&
    type=user_agent&
    display=touch
```

you can implement the FBLoginView in UIWebView and present it.The code is be large so i am giving a link to [Ray Wendelich's Facebook Graph API](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)

Comment: but i need to open Facebook Application ,when the user tap the share button in my app/.is that possible with this API